# InvalidOperationException - object is currently in use elsewhere?

Tags: c#, stream, webcam

I am using a webcam to show live stream, capture images, record video etc using AForge library.

Each time I get a new frame, I assign it to a picture Box to show the live stream and i have added a tool strip for recording video when it is checked. so i did it in the same following method.

```
private void video_NewFrame( object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
   // Assigning new frame to a picturebox
   pictureBox1.Image = newFrame;

    if(recordVideo.Checked)
    {
       writer.AddFrame(newFrame);
    }
}
```

when the record Video tool strip is checked. I open the avi file.

`writer.Open("test.avi", pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);`

and when it is unchecked i close the file.

`writer.Close();`

but when i start recording the video i get the following error:

> Invalid Operation Exception - object is currently in use elsewhere.

Comment: Have you close the writer after you opening it?

Comment: which call exactly (which line in source code) throws the exception?

Comment: Yes.
I close the file when i uncheck the start recording toolstrip.

Comment: @DrKoch
when it comes to write a Frame (Add frame) it throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it like this

```
pictureBox1.Image = newFrame.Clone() as Bitmap;
```

Comment: It started recording but when i start debugging my application from VS it throws the same error.
And when i run the complied app it works fine but consumes alot of memory. Memory reservation goes high and then goes down, it repeats the same processes even if the app is closed unless and until i forcefully end the processes.

Comment: You should use        writer.AddFrame(newFrame.Clone() as bitmap);      As well, anyway it should consume memory as it stores a lot of frames in memory, if my answer helped you please tag it as answer